# Ruby: Offset interpreted differently by Time and DateTime

Tags: ruby, parsing, time, datetimeoffset

Does anyone know why `Time.parse` seems to misinterpret the offset??

```
# Correct:
ruby-1.9.2-p136 > DateTime.parse "2011-04-07T13:53:00-3"
 => Thu, 07 Apr 2011 13:53:00 -0300 

ruby-1.9.2-p136 > Time.parse "2011-04-07T13:53:00-3"
 => 2011-04-07 13:53:00 +0300
```

The format doesn't seem to make any difference:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :027 > Time.parse "2011-04-07T13:53:00-0300"
 => 2011-04-07 19:53:00 +0300 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :028 > Time.parse "2011-04-07T13:53:00-03"
 => 2011-04-07 19:53:00 +0300 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :029 > Time.parse "2011-04-07T13:53:00-03:00"
 => 2011-04-07 19:53:00 +0300
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Time.parse converts it into your timezone. So when you are in +3 and you give it a time of 13.53:00-3, it will be 19.53:00+3 local time for you.

Also if you look at the [Ruby Doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9/classes/Time.html#M000325) you will see that the Time#parse method only understands the timezone abbreviations described in [RFC 822](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc822/#z28) and the system timezone.

So you should use "-0300" instead of "-3".

Comment: The first part makes sense. I had actually tried "-0300" as you can see in the examples lower, but the outcome was the same.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. Just wanted to mention it.